# Error to install Ruby on Rails on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, installation

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit (6.1, Build 7600)

Installing Ruby: I have installed Ruby version 1.8.7 successfully
Installing Rails: I tried to install Rails and all dependencies by typing the following command in command prompt:
gem install rails --include-dependencies

But unfortunately, error was occurred as below:

INFO:  `gem install -y` is now default and will be removed
INFO:  use --ignore-dependencies to install only the gems you list
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

What is the step to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

```
Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads'
and follow the instructions at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

Seems to indicate what is missing on your environment: build tools, also known as a compiler toolchain.

RubyInstaller provides a ready-to-use package called Development Kit (DevKit) which seems to be indicated in the above links.

Also, the wiki page contains all the instructions to download and install it.

If you want to use Rails, instead of using RubyInstaller, why not install directly [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) which already integrates the DevKit and there is no extra installation step.

Hope that helps.